# Creating image through input pixel values with the Python Imaging Library (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm wanting to work on an idea using images but I can't get it to write pixel values properly, it always just ends up grey with some pattern like artefacts, and no matter what I try, the artefacts change but the image remains grey.

Here's the basic code I have:

```
from PIL import Image
data = ""
for i in range( 128**2 ):
    data += "(255,0,0),"
im = Image.fromstring("RGB", (128,128), data)
im.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

There is no information in http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm on how to format `data`, so I've tried using 0-1, 0-255, 00000000-111111111 (binary), brackets, square bracks, no brackets, extra value for alpha and changing RGB to RGBA (which turns it light grey but that's it), comma after, and no comma after, but absolutely nothing has worked.

For the record, I'm not wanting to just store a single colour, I'm just doing this to initially get it working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The format string should be arranged like:

"RGBRGBRGBRGB..."

Where R is a single character indicating the red value of a particular pixel, and the same for G and B.

"But 255 is three characters long, how can I turn that into a single character?" you ask. Use `chr` to convert your numbers into byte values.

```
from PIL import Image
data = ""
for i in range( 128**2 ):
    data += chr(255) + chr(0) + chr(0)
im = Image.fromstring("RGB", (128,128), data)
im.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

Result:

[image]

---

Alternative solution:

Using `fromstring` is a rather roundabout way to generate an image if your data isn't already in that format. Instead, consider using `Image.load` to directly manipulate pixel values. Then you won't have to do any string conversion stuff.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new("RGB", (128, 128))
pix = im.load()
for x in range(128):
    for y in range(128):
        pix[x,y] = (255,0,0)

im.save("test.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: Ahh thanks a bunch, works great :)   My idea was to open an image, and modify values per pixel before saving it again to store data (saw someone else who'd done it and thought it'd be interesting), so I'll try both ways and see what works best

Comment: I think alternative solution will be much more memory-effective for big images.