# Is there a command in PIL that is like the reverse operation to getdata()

Tags: python

So I have the following code that gets the rgb value of an image in a list like shown:

```
from PIL import Image
imageInput = Image.open("gradient.png")
r = list(imageInput.getdata())
print(r)
```

it returns r as an array, now, I have another code that alters that array to change the rgb value, is there a function in PIL that can feed the array to python so it can change the color of the image?

(I have digged through the PIL document and couldn't find anything)

Comment: Check out the answer someone posted for my question, shows how to load, edit pixels and save an image - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445694/creating-image-through-input-pixel-values-with-the-python-imaging-library-pil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [putdata()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.putdata) method:

```
from PIL import Image

imageInput = Image.open("gradient.png")

# convert every tuple to a list:
r = [list(x) for x in imageInput.getdata()]

# Make your changes
for i in range(len(r)):
    r[i][1] = 100
    
# After you are done editing, convert back to tuple:
r = tuple(tuple(x) for x in r)

imageInput.putdata(r)
imageInput.save("new_gradient.png")
```

Comment: Thank you for adding how to convert them properly into list